# My shapes have too many points for plotter to cut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I am using Illustrator to make graphics for T-shirts that we cut out using a plotter. I have created the graphic below but as you can see it has a lot of points close to each other and it takes ages for my plotter to cut them out.

How do I make a smoother line so it's easier to cut?

[image: The immage has a lot of vectors]

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Adobe Illustrator the you can go to `Object > Path > Simplify...` and then tweak the values to reduce the number of points as required. This may result in a slightly simplified design, but you should be able to find a good compromise with the available settings.

Comment: Yes that works to some extent but it doesn't do anything to significant. If i crank it to high it destroys the design

Comment: Maybe try applying this to each element individually. Judging by the screenshot, there are not many redundant points in the main, central bit of the design, but lots of redundant points in the outlying blobs. You may find that different settings work for the different parts.

Comment: That actually worked like a charm, i would have never thought of that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -3):

In addition to the above answered provided by Chris, if the design is inter connected. It would not jump and increase the time duration.

Comment: how do i check if it's inter connected?